# how to pass the manual time into the input type="time" in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know you are fedup with these kind of repeated questions but still now i didn't find answer for my question so please help me to solve this.. Thanks in advance.

html is :

```js
var start="10:30 PM";
$scope.edit={}

frtime=start.split("PM")[0];
               frtime = frtime.trim();
               frtime= $filter('date')(frtime, "HH:mm");
               
               $scope.edit.fromtime=new Date("2010-12-28T"+frtime+":00");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="time" ng-model="edit.fromtime">
```

It is showing some time in the input type field in html. But i need the 10.30 PM in the input field.

Comment: try ng-model="{{edit.fromtime}}">

Comment: The problem is with the date function. see am passing the time in the new Date() function so it adds the time with the GMT and displays some wrong time.. so how to overcome from this..i need to pass the stored time in the input type="time"

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mufa1wvy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS Date object has methods for setting the hours, minutes, etc:

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setHours(10,30,0)
```

Just create a new date, then set it to whatever value you need to:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TS8OtntFw03aKGo9i8K3?p=preview)

All the methods are [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Your version of angularjs is too old:

**JS:**

```
 angular.module('timeExample', [])
   .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.example = {
       value: new Date(1970, 0, 1, 14, 57, 0)
     };
   }]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" />
```

V1.2.23 => It does not work
http://plnkr.co/edit/AA9maTSXiguuglrj1yPJ?p=preview (Example)

V1.3.0 => Do work
http://plnkr.co/edit/8a8laopSX0S0AiW8E6OE?p=preview (Example)

Answer (score 0):

We can write a common method like below:

```
getFormatDate = function (val) { // assuming val is date like "/Date(946673340000)/"
 if (val != undefined) {
    date = new Date(val.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); // creating a date object from val
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
 date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());
 }
}
```